# Low quality image when setting an imageview drawable from a gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have an activity that displays the gallery images in a `GridView`. Above the gridview, there's an ImageView that shows the image chosen from the `GridView` (when clicked).
The problem appears when I get the drawable from the gridview and then set it in the `ImageView`.The quality of the `ImageView` is very low.

The ImageView properties are: `ScaleTye="FitXY", Width="match_parent", Height="wrap_content"`

Any suggestion? Thank you!

```
public class FotoGaleria extends AppCompatActivity {

private Cursor cursor;
private ArrayList<String> images;
private int columnIndex;
ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
ImageView imagen;
Drawable dr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foto_galeria);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .95), (int) (height * .8));

    GridView gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView);
    imagen= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagengrande);

    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {

            if (null != images && !images.isEmpty())


                imagen.setImageDrawable(((ImageView) arg1).getDrawable());



        }
    });

}

/**
 * The Class ImageAdapter.
 */
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /** The context. */
    private Activity context;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new image adapter.
     *
     * @param localContext
     *            the local context
     */
    public ImageAdapter(Activity localContext) {
        context = localContext;
        images = getAllShownImagesPath(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            picturesView = new ImageView(context);
            picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            picturesView
                    .setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(126, 126));

        } else {
            picturesView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagengrande);
        Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nofoto).centerCrop()
                .into(picturesView);

        return picturesView;
    }

    /**
     * Getting All Images Path.
     *
     * @param activity
     *            the activity
     * @return ArrayList with images Path
     */
    private ArrayList<String> getAllShownImagesPath(Activity activity) {
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

        cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);

        }

        return listOfAllImages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the bad quality of image is because of the **glide**.
 Glide stores the image with the resolution of imageview, as per your code, the imageview size 126x126. And then in your activity you get the drawable which is loaded in the imageview which is of size 126x126.

So in order to have full size image, you can modify your code as follows:
First of all move the `getAllShownImagesPath(context)` to your activity and make the arraylist there and pass it to the adapter. Thus you will have all the images list in activity as well.
Now in `gallery.setOnItemClickListener`, you can simply write as follows

```
Glide.with(context).load(imageslist.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_nofoto).centerCrop()
                .into(imagen);
```

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The image in the actual view has already been adjusted by `Glide` to fit that view. What you should do is, use `Glide` again to load image into the view. As `Glide` caches the images, there will be no delay.